# How should I clear media after disconnecting video call using easyrtc api functions?

Tags: javascript, easyrtc

I am using this function:

```
easyrtc.setOnStreamClosed( function (callerEasyrtcid) {
    easyrtc.setVideoObjectSrc(document.getElementById('caller'),"");
});
```

but it is not working..

Comment: Did you try `easyrtc.clearMediaStream(document.getElementById('caller'))` ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried this clearMediaStream function() also but it is not working..